# What is the DIN standard for a business letter?

Tags: standard-german

I'm told that there is a DIN standard that specifies the format of a business letter in Germany.

What standard is it, and where can I find it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wikipedia tells me it is [DIN 5008](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_5008) and there paragraph 16 and 17. Be assured that, in my experience, not all German businesses are using it or are even aware that such thing exists. (at least the bad students aren't).